# nextjs 13 with scss what this weird happen with height?

Tags: html, css, sass, next.js13

This is a css(scss).

```scss
html {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: $bg-color-f4f4f4;

    .base {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      max-width: 22.5rem;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;

      header {
        height: $height-header;
        background-color: $bg-color-0e0340;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: end;
      }

      main {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        min-height: calc(100% - $height-header - $height-footer);
      }

      footer {
        height: $height-footer;
      }
    }
  }
}

.login {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $bg-color-17b75e;
}
```

When with height auto
[image]

with height 0
[image]

I'm using Next.js 13. When I test this code using plain HTML with a style attribute, this issue doesn't occur.

---

[Added]

This html's div.login's height 100% no matter height: auto or not.

```html
<html lang="en" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <body>
        <div style="width: 22.5rem;
                height: 100%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;">
            <header></header>
            <main style="width: 100%; height: auto; min-height: calc(100% - 5rem);">
                <div class="login" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    Hello!
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Next.js 13. When I test this code using plain HTML with a style attribute, this issue doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

It's expected, as stated on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.php):

> The min-height property defines the minimum height of an element.
>
> **If the content is smaller than the minimum height, the minimum height
> will be applied.**
>
> **If the content is larger than the minimum height, the min-height
> property has no effect.**

As you can see in the first screenshot, the `<div>` with the class `login` has a height of `21.6px`. As soon as you add `height: 0;`, the `min-height` is applied.

Comment: If i changed <main> height: 0 to height: auto, rendered like first image. height: auto also smaller then min-height.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `height: 0;` or `height: auto;`? What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is for the 'div.login' element to have the same height as the 'main' element when the 'main' element's height is set to 'auto'.